# How can i populate array of items in my collections schema with mongoose and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

i am creating items to specific collections and when i get collections i want to retrieve all items in it. i referenced items array in my collections schema and referenced collection id in my items schema. So when i get items i can populate collections but when i populate items array in my collections *get* request it is returning empty items array. Can u help me to populate items array in my collections using mongoose?

[image]

**COLLECTION SCHEMA**

```
const collectionSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String },
    description: { type: String },
    owner: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
    items: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Item" }],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

**ITEMS SCHEMA**

```
const itemSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String },
    description: { type: String },
    owner: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
    collections: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Collection" },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

**COLLECTIONS GET REQUEST**

```
collectionRoute.get("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const collection = await CollectionModal.find({}).populate({
      path: "owner",
      select: "username",
    }).populate("items");
    res.status(200).send(collection);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: You have a typo, `populate ("itemS");` should be `populate ("items");`

Comment: i changed but did not work :(